# :focus issues with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relatively new with ReactJS and I'm trying to implement a small form that contains an input text field and a search button. I'm using the :focus pseudo-selector on the input field so when the user enters information it increases the width to 2000% and when the element loses focus it goes back to width:130%.

The problem I'm having is when I click my search button for the first time the input field shrinks back to the original position but it doesn't do the search until I click it for the second time. If I type something and then click somewhere else to loose focus it works like a charm.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../base/header'
import axios from 'axios'
import SearchResults from './searchResults'
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import Radium from 'radium';

class Search extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)

        this.state = {
            searchTerm: "",
            searchResultsList: ""
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleCallback = this.handleCallback.bind(this);

    }

    handleCallback() {

        console.log("calling handleSubmit");
    }


    handleSubmit() {

        var that = this
        event.preventDefault();

        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/users/findusers', {

            searchTerm: this.state.searchTerm

        }).then(function (response) {

            console.log("data sent");
            that.setState({searchResultsList: response.data})

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    handleChange(e) {

        this.setState({searchTerm: e.target.value}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.searchTerm);

        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                            transitionName="search-input"
                            transitionAppear={true}
                            transitionAppearTimeout={500}
                            transitionEnter={false}
                            transitionLeave={false}>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                style={styles.inputStyle}
                                value={this.state.searchTerm}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                placeholder="Find Friends..."
                            />

                            {/*<img onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()} */}

                            <img src="/icons/svg/magnifying-glass.svg"
                                     alt="Search" className="searchIcon"
                             onClick={() => this.handleCallback()}
                            />
                            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                </div>
                </form>

                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-3">left</div>
                        {/* Main Area */}
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <SearchResults
                             searchResultsList={this.state.searchResultsList}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-3">right</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const styles = {

    inputStyle: {
        marginTop: 5,
        marginLeft: 20,
        width: 130,
        WebkitTransition: 'width 0.4s easeInOut',
        msTransition: 'width 0.4s easeInOut',
        ':focus': {
            width: '2000%'
        }
    }
};

export default Radium(Search)
```

I originally had the code in a separate CSS file and decided to make it inline to see if there was any difference. I tried creating different functions to see if there was any difference but is still behaving the same.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Are sure `width` is a good way to check focus? Maybe it would work with `borderColor`?

Comment: Thank you. I wondered the same and I tried with backgroundColor: 'green' just to give it a shot. Both the width and backgroundColor work as soon as the element get the focus but is still making the issue when clicking the search button.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the width changing when clicking the magnifying glass. I believe it is because the `:focus` property is on the input and not the div containing the input and img.

I would recommend using the `:focus-within` property on the parent div. Here is an example of divs with both properties.

```css
#div1:focus-within > input {
  width: 300px;
}

#div2 > input:focus {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <input type="text"/>
  <button>Search</button>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <input type="text"/>
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

This should solve the focusing issue.

Not sure why your magnifying glass image works so strangely. When reading the code it seems that clicking the image calls `handleCallback()` which is only logging not submitting.

Not sure if this helps but I would recommend using a button or input element for submission. The button would have `type="submit"` with the magnifying glass image as the child. The input would have `type="submit" value=""` and set the CSS `background-image:` to the magnifying glass.

Comment: Awesome! Your solution works great, I changed my CSS as you suggested and instead of using the input type = "submit" I used a <button> element and enclosed my image as a child containing the onClick attribute. I truly appreciate your help Marvin!